# Existence of countable perfect sets?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Does there exist a countable perfect set? (I know that if the parent metric is complete then this is not possible) However I couldn't construct any complete perfect sets from non complete metric spaces. Nor could I find/derive a proof that every perfect set is uncountable without appealing to the completeness of the space. 
I had an intuition of "extending" the space to complete it and then using the completeness property to say that the new space is uncountable, but the problem is that we might end up adding uncountable elements during "extension" to the set and thus we end up making it uncountable. 
Help would be appreciated
(PS a perfect set here means a closed subspace of a metric space with every point being a limit point)

Answer (score 6):

For example, take the space to be the rationals.  $\mathbb Q$ is a countable perfect subset of $\mathbb Q$.